# how do i collect dms and send them into a channel on a server

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make the bot receive DMS and send the received DMS into a channel. It already creates the channel and dms the user on command but idk how to receive & send the received dms in a channel. thanks for helping:)

```
run(client, message, args) {
    

    message.guild.channels
      .create(this.name, { type: 'text', })
      .then((channel) => {
        const catogaryID = '850020908596592713'
        channel.setParent(catogaryID)
      })
    message.channel.send('<@839172815025340426> s1 needs help')

    message.author.send('whats wrong')
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly you're trying to send DMs from a certain user into a specific channel. Is that right?

Comment: You can use [DMChannel#awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

Comment: @Dinty yeah thats what im trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a Map which stores the user's name and the channel that you want to post their messages to, something like this:

In your main file somewhere

```
// Stores the information somewhere that it can easily be retrieved
client.modmailThreads = new Map(); // I'm assuming this is what you want to achieve
```

Listening to new messages

```
client.on("message", message => {

  // Your other code here


  if(message.channel.type == "dm" && client.modmailThreads.get(message.author.id)) { // If this is a DM and the user has a modmail channel
    client.channels.cache.get(client.modmailThreads.get(message.author.id)).send(message.content); // Get their modmail channel and send the message to it
  }

});
```

In your current code

```
run(client, message, args) {
    

    message.guild.channels
      .create(this.name, { type: 'text', })
      .then((channel) => {
        const catogaryID = '850020908596592713'
        channel.setParent(catogaryID)
        client.modmailThreads.set(message.author.id, channel.id); // Store value
      })
    message.channel.send('<@839172815025340426> s1 needs help')

    message.author.send('whats wrong')
```

Obviously this is only an example so you may want to do some more modifications yourself.

Comment: it works now but every time a new channel is created and another channel exists it duplicates the message sent into the channel

Comment: what im saying is it duplicates the message when there's more then one channel

Comment: What do you mean it's duplicated? Is the DM sending to all of the open channels?